# html form remove inputs from url

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm using standard html form for login. like this

```
<form submit.delegate="login()"> 
     <input name="email" type="text">
     <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password"> 
     <button type="submit>SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

The problem I'm facing is that sometimes the `submit.delegate` messes up and redirects me to url where all params are in plaintext like this `http://localhost:9001/?email=myemail%40gmail.com&password=12345`. How can I stop that? I could switch `form` to `div` instead beacuse I'm really only using it so enter key would automatically submit it? Should I do that or is there some better way to tell form to do nothing after `login()` method call? Keep in mind creating object and posting it is done programmatically so form doesn't have anything to do with that.

Comment: Because you are not defining any **method** attribute with form element, it is assigned as **GET** by default and in case of **GET** all of your form data will get showed in url. Use **method=post** in form element `<form method=post>`

Comment: Take a look at `POST` requests, or better yet `oAuth`.

Comment: When I use method="post" then form redirects me to blank page with error `Cannot POST /`

Answer (score 1):

You use GET, so all the datas will be visible through URL.
You should use POST to hide them.

use the attribute `method="POST"` on your `<form>` tag.
So: `<form submit.delegate="login()" method="POST">`

To use the field's values on the target page, you will have to change `$_GET['input_name']` with `$_POST['input_name']`

Have a look : 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp